# Change Maven settings at build time

Tags: maven, deployment, artifactory

I would like to deploy my Maven build to an Artifactory repo. This repo requires authentication, but I would prefer not modifying my settings.xml file. Is there a way to provide the credentials at build time? I know that you can set properties in the POM with the -D switch:

```
mvn clean package -Dmy.prop=blah
```

Is there a way to do something similar to provide the contents of a `<server>` block in the settings.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Maven Artifactory plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin), which accepts credentials in pom file and use the `-D` as intended.

And, of course, you'll get the full build-info support :)

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare separate settings.xml file for build purpose and use this by -s options.

Eg.

```
mvn -s build_settings.xml clean deploy
```

Comment: Thanks, this was good to know about. Unfortunately, I don't want to keep the credentials in my codebase. What I'd like to do is just provide them when I build, using something akin to the -D option. This way, I could keep those credentials in something like Jenkins or Bamboo. The Maven Artifactory plugin seems to allow this, after a fashion.